# Why won't images show up in copyright section of WordPress website?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to add a Creative Commons image to the footer of my websites and the image simply won't display.

One of the websites (https://thegalleryof.me/) was created using Divi and when adding the code to the copyright section, the image appears in the preview, but after publishing and going to the site, it's not there. Even looking at the source code I found that the *img* tag was gone, only the *a* tag was present.

This is the code I've added:

```
<a rel="license" href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/"><img alt="Creative Commons License" style="border-width:0" src="https://i.creativecommons.org/l/by-nc-nd/4.0/88x31.png"/></a>
```

I've tried simply adding an image from my own website and that doesn't show up either (not even in the source code after publishing).

On another website using a regular theme (https://blog.ovidiuav.com/) the image (or any image) doesn't even show up in the preview.

I have no idea why this is happening, hoping someone can enlighten me.

Thank you!

Comment: Divi strips out images from the footer credits textarea. You would either have to add a widget in that area, or create a child theme and hard code it in to the HTML.

Comment: Huh, I've never heard of that. The second website doesn't use Divi, but I guess it's just doing the same thing. Guess I'll use a child theme like you said, thanks for that!

Comment: Actually, I'm looking at the source code and that section seems to be under a div with a "copyright" class. I'm wondering if there isn't an easier way to take care of this using CSS.

Comment: If the image doesn't exist in the html markup there isn't much you can do with CSS, other than creating a pseudo element and adding the image as a background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WizardCoder [commented above with the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56617607/why-wont-images-show-up-in-copyright-section-of-wordpress-website/56715013#comment99848876_56617607):

> Divi strips out images from the footer credits textarea. You would either have to add a widget in that area, or create a child theme and hard code it in to the HTML.
>   If the image doesn't exist in the html markup there isn't much you can do with CSS, other than creating a pseudo element and adding the image as a background.